# How to use Google Calendar API in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, google-calendar-api

I want to learn Kotlin to create an android app, as a challenge I want to use Google Calendar API. I checked its site and there is support for Java, Python etc, yet I did not see Kotlin. Does that mean I can't use it or are there are ways to run Java code in Kotlin?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kotlin runs in the JVM, which means you should be able to use the Java API from Kotlin, although you'll probably need a few modifications to make it work.

Comment: By modifications do you mean modifying the JVM? How difficult would it be? Or as a different way should I write the Android app in Java? Or I dont know if this is possible but run the Google calendar api part in Python but write the app in Kotlin? Thanks for the quick response by the way!

Comment: Once they've been compiled, classes on the JVM are pretty much the same, regardless of whether they were compiled from Java source or Kotlin source.  So if the Google Calendar API has a Java library, you can use it from Kotlin code in exactly the same way as you would from Java code.  The only difference would be that it wouldn't take advantage of Kotlin features such as null safety or function types.  (And that your code would have to use Kotlin syntax, not Java syntax, of course!)

Comment: Allright then I think I understand it, I will have to try and see. Thanks for the help!